# View External Dependecy graph in NDepend

Tags: ndepend, static-code-analysis, dependency-graph

NDepend has a nice feature that draws an **internal** dependency graph. That is which methods within a dll call each other.

We would like a diagram like this that showed how methods were called across all dll's in a project. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Dependency Matrix, you can select the cell that represents the dependency between the 2 assemblies (in the screenshot below *punit-agent.dll* and *nunit-util.dll*) and just left click it...

[image: Dependency Matrix]

...and a method dependency graph is generated. Is it what you are asking for?

[image: Dependency Graph]

Notice in the first screenshot the parameter *Weight on Cell* that is set to *# members*. If you set to *# types* or *# namespaces*, you'll get a graph with types or namespaces.

Comment: You are welcome Shiraz, you have more graph tricks here: http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx